# Will Brexit have any impact on UK recognition of foreign licenses

Tags: united-states, legal, united-kingdom

As a US license holder (and duel citizen of the US and UK) I know that I can operate in the UK for a couple of months using the M/W2*** prefix, while holding Amateur Extra, but I cannot apply for a UK license using my US license, like Japan for example which has exchanges.

So I have three questions for the minds out there in Stack Exchange,

1. Will Brexit affect this situation.
2. Can I still operate over there when travel resumes?
3. Will there be movement so that there is cross recognition of more foreign license holders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No.
2. Yes.
3. There's no particular reason to think so.

The UK and the US have both adopted CEPT T/R 61-01 regarding reciprocal amateur operation. Despite the fact that CEPT is the "European Conference of Postal and Telecommunications Administrations", it's independent of the EU (it long predates the EU), and parties to T/R 61-01 don't have to be members of the EU or members of CEPT (the US, Canada, Australia, New Zealand, Peru, and South Africa are non-CEPT members).

So Brexit has no "automatic" impact, and I don't see any reason why the UK would go out of their way to terminate the existing arrangement. In any case, they're probably far too busy to give it any thought ;)